# Why does the below mentioned hex color code visually have the same color as the 6 digit hex code?

Tags: css

I understand that the standard hex color code format is 6 digit hexadecimal `#RRGGBB`. But why does the following 2 versions show similar color (at least visually) `#RGB` and `#R0G0B0`?

Example:

- `#A1BD24` - the standard 6 digit hex color code (a shade of green)
- `#AB2` - (taking 1st digit from each of the 2 digit pair in `#RRGGBB`)
- `#A0B020` -replacing the 2nd digit of every 2 digit pair in `#RRGGBB` with 0

All 3 appear green. Is it that the 2nd digit of every 2 digit pair in `#RRGGBB` represents a shade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that second digit in each pair represents a shade. This is calculated from the hexadecimal representation of the number. Specifically, this is `x * 16 * x` for each pair. For example, `F` has a hexadecimal value of `15`, so the pair `FF` would be `15 * 16 + 15`. This would give you `255`, which is the maximum value possible.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.color1 {
  background: #A1BD24; /* rgb(161, 189, 36) */
}

.color2 {
  background: #A0B020; /* rgb(160, 176, 32) */
}

.color3 {
  background: #AB2; /* rgb(170, 187, 34) */
}

.color4 {
  background: #AABB22; /* rgb(170, 187, 34) */
}
```

```html
<div class="color1">Test 1</div>
<div class="color2">Test 2</div>
<div class="color3">Test 3</div>
<div class="color4">Test 4</div>
```

Note that the shorthand syntax `#RGB` is short for `#RRGGBB`, **NOT** `#R0G0B0`; `.color3` is equal to `.color4`, not `.color2`.

Comment: "Shade" is a very colloquial and arbitrary term. The first and second digits of each pair don't represent different things. Each "pair" is a two-digit hex number representing the R, G or B component, calculated exactly as you describe. This isn't something like the HSL scale.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 digit code is just a shorthand for the 6 digit where every second digit in the pair is a repeat of the first digit.

So: `#xyz` is the same as `#xxyyzz` (not `#x0y0z0` as you are suggesting)

The relevant spec is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-css-color-3-20180619/#rgb-color

and the relevant section I will paste below:

> The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a ‘#’ immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters. The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example, #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies on the color depth of the display.

The next iteration of the colour spec actually adds support for 4 and 8 character colours too. In these the extra digit (or pair) represents the alpha channel. You can read this spec here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation

Comment: but aren't they two different hexadecimal numbers? For example, when you convert them to decimal, you get two different values. How could they possibly have the same color then?

Comment: They're not meant to be interpreted as a single hexadecimal number, but as 3 hexadecimal numbers with no separator. I've updated the answer with a link to the spec if you want to read more.

Answer (score 1):

First, `#AB2` evaluates to `#AABB22` instead of `#A0B020`.

Next, to address your question:

> ... why does the following 2 versions show similar color(atleast visually) #RGB and #R0G0B0?

I think it is best explained by using HSL instead of RBG or HEX.

When we [convert the hex values to HSL](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp), we get:

```
#a1bd24 -> hsl(71, 68%, 44%)

#ab2    -> hsl(67, 69%, 43%)
#aabb22 -> hsl(67, 69%, 43%)
#a0b020 -> hsl(67, 69%, 41%)
```

If you are not familiar with HSL, here's a [short article](http://changingminds.org/explanations/perception/visual/hsl.htm) that explains what H, S and L stands for.

**Hue**

Both `#AB2` and `#A0B020` has hue of 67. Meaning the two hex values are actually the *same colour*.

**Saturation**

Both `#AB2` and `#A0B020` has saturation of 69%. Meaning the two hex values are actually the same colour with *same saturation*.

**Luminosity/Lightness** *(or can you say it's shade?)*

Here, `#AB2` and `#A0B020` has 2% difference in lightness. Meaning even though they are essentially the same colour with same saturation, there is a very *slight difference in the actual presentation of the colour*. As the difference is only 2%, we will see *almost no difference* when we perceive them with our eyes.

> Is it that the 2nd digit of every 2 digit pair in #RRGGBB represents a shade?

Not really.

As you can see in the `#A1BD24` example, the only changing digits are the 2nd digit of every 2 digit pair, but its HSL values are completely different with both `#AB2` and `#A0B020`.

Its HUE becomes 71, meaning it's already a different colour (even though it is still very green). So, the statement is incorrect.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#a1bd24 { background-color: #a1bd24; }
#ab2    { background-color: #ab2;    }
#aabb22 { background-color: #aabb22; }
#a0b020 { background-color: #a0b020; }
```

```html
<div id="a1bd24">#A1BD24</div>
<div id="ab2">#AB2</div>
<div id="aabb22">#AABB22</div>
<div id="a0b020">#A0B020</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example where you compare #A1BD24 with #A0B020, they look similar because you are changing the less significant digit of each red, green and blue component, so visually is not very different, specially with the values you used

in RGB,

A1 BD 24 is 161  189  36

and

A0 B0 20 is 160  176  32

so they are very similar values